# How can I get that $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$ is divergent?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I read this at one book. Actually I know how to show this fact, but there was a conclusion from Euler equality.

> Conclusion : using $\zeta(s) = \prod(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}})^{-1}$ we could found out this : $\sum \frac{1}{p} \rightarrow \infty$.

I thought about Cauchy inequality, but I got only upper bound : $\sum (1-\frac{1}{p}) \ge \prod(1-\frac{1}{p})$.

Comment: I have two remarks : 1) $\sum\frac1p$ does not mean anything. 2) What is your question ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom 1) changed 2) how can I get this

Comment: For $Re(s) > 1$ : $\log \zeta(s) = -\sum_p \log(1-p^{-s}) = \sum_p\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k} = \sum_p p^{-s}  + \sum_p\sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$ and the second sum converges since it is $\sum_p\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{p^{- s2k}}{2k} + \frac{p^{- s(2k+1)}}{2k+1}$ $< 2\zeta(2s)$. Hence $\log \zeta(s) \to +\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_p p^{-s} \to +\infty$. Can you finish ?

Comment: The question is still quite unclear. If you do not provide the context, we cannot figure out the proof. For instance, what do you already know about $\zeta$ is a beginning.

Comment: @Tom-Tom this is a standard proof in analytic number theory, showing from the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$ that $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$ diverges ($\sum_p$ means sum over prime numbers)

Comment: @user1952009. Well, if you already know where $\zeta$ diverges... which is absolutely impossible to figure out in the OP's question at the moment.

Comment: $p$ prime : $\sum\limits_{p \leq x}\frac{1}{p} \approx \ln\ln x$ for $x\to\infty$ (a lot of literature exist)

Comment: @user1952009 second transform is Taylor series ?

Comment: @openspace yes but you can replace it by $-\ln(1-x) \sim x$ when $x \to 0$, so $ \frac{p^{-s}}{10} < -\ln(1-p^{-s}) < 10 p^{-s}$ at least for $p$ large enough (and $s > 1$)

Comment: I have seen notation where if you want to say$$\sum_p \bigg(1 - \frac 1p\bigg)$$ for prime $p$ for example, then we put a dash, i.e. $$\sum_p'\bigg(1-\frac 1p\bigg)$$ or simply, just write underneath, $p\text{ prime}$ to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Euler's product we have that for any $s>1$

$$\log\zeta(s) = \sum_{p}-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)=\sum_p\left(\frac{1}{p^s}+\frac{1}{2p^{2s}}+\frac{1}{3p^{3s}}+\ldots\right) $$
holds, but over the interval $(0,1/2]$ the function $f(x)=-\log(1-x)-x$ is bounded in absolute value by $x^2$, hence
$$ \log\zeta(s) = \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s}+O(1). $$
By exploiting Abel's summation formula it is not difficult to prove that $\zeta(s)$ behaves like $\frac{1}{s-1}$ in a right neighbourhood of $s=1$, hence $\lim_{s\to 1^+}\log\zeta(s)=+\infty$ and by the previous formula $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p}$ cannot be convergent.

Answer (score 2):

By using prime number theorem we know,

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime-counting function that gives the number of primes less than or equal to $x$, for any real number $x$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{\frac{x}{\ln x}}=1$$

Hence for the $n$ th prime number $p_n$, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{n\log n}=1$$

But we know when $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ have same behaviour , hence since $\sum\frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges by using [Cauchy test](http://www.math.montana.edu/pernarow/m172/resources/Series_Resources/Series_Cauchy_Condensation.pdf), so $\sum\frac{1}{p_n}$ diverges

I know it from the book of [T.M.Apostol](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387901633) since my BSc